# Dynamic styled component tag based on prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm trying to create a dynamic tag with styled components. The tag is received via props.

This is the code example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

type ContainerProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode,
    type?: 'section' | 'div' | 'article',
}

const Container = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.theme.primaryColor};
`;

const Icon = styled.div<ContainerProps>`
    background-color: red;
`;

const container: React.FunctionComponent<ContainerProps['children']> = ({ children, type = 'section' }: ContainerProps) => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <{ children }
        </Container>
    );
};

export default container;
```

I'm trying to achieve that the `<Container>` tag (which is a `div` now) is a dynamic prop based on the `prop.type`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the ["as" polymorphic prop](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop), like this:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

type ContainerProps = {
    children: React.ReactNode,
    type?: 'section' | 'div' | 'article',
}

const Container = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.theme.primaryColor};
`;

const Icon = styled.div<ContainerProps>`
    background-color: red;
`;

const container: React.FunctionComponent<ContainerProps['children']> = ({ children, type = 'section' }: ContainerProps) => {
    return (
        <Container as={type}>
            { children }
        </Container>
    );
};

export default container;
```

See this [simple codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/6nxkwk8z7z) I put together based on your code