# Styled component with conditional tag

Tags: reactjs, button, styled-components, emotion

I am wondering if there is a solution for the following case. I have a nice button with an icon and lots of styles in the design system. Multiple designers use it to move user to another screen, so use it as a link.

I want to make this component flexible, so if it used as a button render button tag, if as a link, then a.

```
export const ButtonStyled = styled.(link ? a : button)<BaseButtonProps>(({props}) => ({
   // lots of styles
> }));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic styled component tag based on prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592994/dynamic-styled-component-tag-based-on-prop)

Comment: You can use ["as"polymorphic prop](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#as-polymorphic-prop) from styled components.